# Change code from httpClient to httpClient builder. Android API 23+

Tags: java, android, apache, ssl, soap

I am currently struggling to prepare my code for SOAP communication with SOAP protocol behind it (no I can't use JSON). The idea is that I send a certificate for server, that tells me, if the device is allowed to connect and than we developed our system with tokens, which works quite well. I am not sure how API 23 is far, but I am sure that at one point I would need to change my network solution. Everything is working correctly right now.

So far looks like this:

```
private static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
try {
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
              InputStream trustStoreStream = SampleApp.appContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.server);
              trustStore.load(trustStoreStream, "A123456a".toCharArray());

              SSLSocketFactory sslf = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
              sslf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
              SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
              schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme ("https", sslf, 443));

              HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
              HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
              HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
              HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 20000000);
              HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 20000000);

              SingleClientConnManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);

              return new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
 } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return new DefaultHttpClient();
      }
  }
```

And that works fine until i change in my gradle SDK 23, than all of the sudden everything was red. Can someone point me out how to solve this. This application should be secure and it's used by more 1000+ users, which are clients of private company. We've got just jet certificate of security and this happened. I want my application transmission to be as secure as possible. Can someone help me?

Passwords and names was obviously change, for sake of security. Thanks for any help. Maybe I am idiot, but Apache description of functions isn't enough.

Thanks a lot for anyone willing to help.

Comment: org.apache.http package has been removed from the API-23. See Google comment http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client